# Putting output file into var

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have easy .bat file

```
%2 >file.tmp
set /p %1=<file.tmp
```

I expect to use this script in this way:

```
putVar var1 command.bat
```

It should get first line of output command.bat into variable var1
and after that I should be able use var1 variable, for example

```
putVar var1 command.bat
echo %var1%
```

Unfortunately this do not work.
How to get this work? Maybe there is some easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in your sample code the command you are running (`command.bat`) is a batch file, which it is being invoked from inside a batch file, and if from a batch file you call another batch file without using `call` command, then the execution does not return to caller batch.

To keep the syntax, you can use

```
(cmd /c "%~2")>file.tmp
set /p "%~1="<file.tmp
```

spawning a second instance of `cmd` to handle the command, redirecting its output to the temporary file and then reading the file (only the first line of `command.bat` output) into the variable.

A simpler way of doing it is to use `for /f`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%~2') do set "%~1=%%a"
```

which, more or less, do the same work. Run the command retrieve the output and, in this case, iterate over the output of the command, assigning each of the lines of `command.bat` output to the variable. Obviously, only the last line will be stored inside the variable, as the loop will overwrite its value in each iteration.